# How to use COUNTIFS and CONCATENATE together

Tags: excel

I'm having some trouble using countifs & concacenate

```
=countifs($A$2:$A$306="ATIP",$B$2:$B$306="Current",CONCATENATE("*",J2,"*"))
```

Pretty much, I want to count however many times my item in J2 occurs if ATIP & Current is in my chart as well.

Any ideas why Excel is giving me a "you have entered too few arguments" for this? Thanks

Comment: And your actual first two need to be comma separated from the condition  e.g. =countifs($A$2:$A$306,"ATIP",$B$2:$B$306,"Current",

Comment: But I don't have anything else to add or to search for? How do I cut the function off as is?

Comment: What is the purpose of CONCATENATE("",J2,"") ? It isn't a range. Was it indended as a test condition? If so, for which range?

Comment: Pretty much I have a bunch of words in a pivot table that are joined together, I want to see if something contains the word I've put in J2. 

Concatenate might not be the right function, but how can you reference a string within a cell?

Comment: If something where? you need a third range that is the same size as A2:A306. And you aren't concatenating J2 with anything. It is simply J2.

Comment: LOL. Well then.. That was easy - Okay so I'm now seeing that concatenate is the wrong function, is there some way I can reference a cell to search for a specific word instead of typing "whateverword" ?

Comment: See my answer below where I have explained the Countifs and shown you how to use Search and Find.

Comment: Your question appears to have been update to include wildcards, *, so I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) goes

> COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
>
> The COUNTIFS function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> criteria_range1    Required. The first range in which to evaluate the
>   associated criteria.
>
> criteria1    Required. The criteria in the form of a number,
>   expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be
>   counted. For example, criteria can be expressed as 32, ">32", B4,
>   "apples", or "32".
>
> criteria_range2, criteria2, ...    Optional. Additional ranges and
>   their associated criteria. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.

So your criteria are comma separated from the condition. It goes range1, condition1, range2, condition2 etc. And the ranges must be of the same dimensions. You are getting an error because you have not specified a condition for the third test but in fact, if you corrected the start syntax as well, you would need something like as follows.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$306,"ATIP",$B$2:$B$306,"Current",$C$2:$C$306,"*" & J2 "*" &)
```

I have arbitrarily selected `$C$2:$C$306` as the third range as it has the same dimensions and is the next column along.

---

If simply checking if a cell contains a word use `Find` or `Search` functions.

Example, using `Search` on cell J2 to find the word `"Word"`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Word*",J2)),"Found","Not Found")
```

Using Find

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*Word*",J2)),"Found","Not Found")
```

Note that `Find` is case senstive so will match on `"Word"` not `"word"`.